# how long will it take to execute a ten-stage pipeline

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

Suppose you design a computer with a `ten-stage` Pipeline to execute one instruction, with each stage taking `5nsec`

A)how long will it take to execute a program that has `30 sequential` instructions. 
**Answer: 195nsec**

B) how long will it take to execute a program that has `30 sequential instructions` in a `non-pipeline computer`
**Answer: 1500nsec**

can some one please help me to understand how was the answer achieved.